Maximum value of sum of $\sin$ of $3$ angles whose sum $0$

If $A+B+C=0.$ Then Maximum value of $\displaystyle |\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C)|$ is

What I try : Let $\displaystyle K=2\sin\bigg(\frac{A+B}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{A-B}{2}\bigg)+2\sin^2\bigg(\frac{C}{2}\bigg)-1$
$\displaystyle K=-2\sin\bigg(\frac{C}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{A-B}{2}\bigg)+2\sin^2\bigg(\frac{C}{2}\bigg)-1$
$\displaystyle K=\bigg(\sin^2\frac{C}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}\bigg)^2-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\cos^2\frac{A-B}{2}$
Now I did not understand how I solve it after that, Please have a look on that problem, Thanks.

Are there any restrictions? Like $A,B,C≤π$ or something?

Actually Here $A=P-Q, B=Q-R$ and $C=R-P$ and $P,Q,R$ are angle of Triangle $PQR$

How does direct optimization of $(\sin A + \sin B + \sin (-A - B))^2$ by calculus fare?

Letting $x := |\cos \frac{C}{2}|$, by triangle inequality and AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 f &:= |\sin A + \sin B + \sin C|\\[6pt]
 &= \left|2\sin\frac{A + B}{2} \cos \frac{A - B}{2} + \sin C\right| \\[6pt]
 &= \left|- 2\sin \frac{C}{2} \cos \frac{A - B}{2} + 2\sin \frac{C}{2} \cos \frac{C}{2}\right|\\[6pt]
 &= \left|2\sin \frac{C}{2}\right|\cdot \left|\cos \frac{C}{2} - \cos \frac{A - B}{2}\right|\\
 &\le \left|2\sin \frac{C}{2}\right|\cdot \left|\Big|\cos \frac{C}{2}\Big| + \Big| \cos \frac{A - B}{2}\Big|\right|\\[6pt]
 &\le \left|2\sin \frac{C}{2}\right|\cdot \left|\Big|\cos \frac{C}{2}\Big| + 1\right|\\[6pt]
 &= \sqrt{4(1 - x^2)(x + 1)^2}\\
 &= \sqrt{\frac43 \cdot 3(1 - x) \cdot (1 + x) \cdot (1 + x) \cdot (1 + x)}\\
 &\le \sqrt{\frac43\cdot \left(\frac{3(1 - x) + (1 + x) + (1 + x)  + (1 + x)}{4}\right)^4}\\
 &= \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, when $A = B = 2\pi/3$ and $C = -4\pi/3$, we have $A + B + C = 0$ and
$|\sin A + \sin B + \sin C| = 3\sqrt{3}/2$.
Thus, the maximum is $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
